# Simple OpenGL based Camera Class

Tags: c++, opengl, open-source, camera

I'm looking for a simple yet complete camera implementation (library) for OpenGL. My use case is rendering volumetric models - which I'm visualizing with glut. But my current camera implementation is a bit buggy.

After googling I found a few implementations such as those found in NeHe however they don't have all the functionality I'm after, specifically:

1. Left, Right
2. Strafe
3. Rotation about viewing axis
4. Arbitrary translation of viewing point

Any DirectX solutions that can be easily converted into OpenGL will also be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Arbitrary translation of viewing point" ? That you need to control the camera target directly with the keyboard ? Or that the camera's position should be controllable ? Or something else ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to explain it but given where the pin-hole camera is hypothetically positioned the frustum and direction where the camera is looking, there is a vector that goes through center of this construction, i'd like to be able to rotate the camera about this particular axis.

Comment: Indeed : they are an infinity of such vectors. Do you want : the UP vector of the world ? The UP vector of your camera ? The FRONT vector of your camera ? Something else ? Don't hesitate to upload a little drawing...

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=Quaternion_Camera_Class?

Comment: Yes, i don't believe it supports rotations about the viewing axis. I'm not really good at math, so i was hoping for an all-in-one solution - it seems like such a common problem.

Comment: @Jared: Of course it can do it. The viewing axis is the camera local Z axis, and CreateFromAxis angle operates on the local frame.

Comment: This page no longer exists, maybe there is an updated link?

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not sure about the question, I'm going to tentatively answer with a tutorial of mine :

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/

(source code [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/download/))

Hope that helps. If it does not completely fulfills your needs, don't hesitate to explain exactly what is wrong, and I'll edit my post.